# `boost` `Signal2` library conflicts with Microsoft memory leak detection?

Tags: c++, boost, memory-leaks

I have portable Linux/Windows application. I use `boost` `Signal2` library to implement events system.

Microsoft has built-in memory leak detection feature in Visual C++. You have to include some code at the very beginning of any source file to replace normal `malloc` and `new` with theirs debug versions, and these debug memory management functions generate memory leak report when application exits. The code follows:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG 
    #define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <crtdbg.h>  
    #ifndef DBG_NEW      
        #define DBG_NEW new ( _NORMAL_BLOCK , __FILE__ , __LINE__ )      
        #define new DBG_NEW   
    #endif
#endif
```

When I include this code, the program stops to compile. Error messages are not understandable and don't even point to source file where the error occurred (they point to `boost` headers, but not to my program headers or code files). Error report follows:

```
D:\src\open-source\boost\boost/variant/detail/initializer.hpp(122): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'dest'
1>          D:\src\open-source\boost\boost/variant/detail/initializer.hpp(116) : while compiling class template member function 'int boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<T1,T2>::initializer_node::initialize(void *,boost::shared_ptr<void> &&)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T1=boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::initializer_root,boost::mpl::int_<0>>
1>  ,            T2=boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list2<boost::shared_ptr<void>,boost::signals2::detail::foreign_void_shared_ptr>>
1>          ]
1>          D:\src\open-source\boost\boost/variant/variant.hpp(1559) : see reference to function template instantiation 'int boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<T1,T2>::initializer_node::initialize(void *,boost::shared_ptr<void> &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T1=boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::initializer_root,boost::mpl::int_<0>>
1>  ,            T2=boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list2<boost::shared_ptr<void>,boost::signals2::detail::foreign_void_shared_ptr>>
1>          ]
1>          D:\src\open-source\boost\boost/variant/detail/initializer.hpp(76) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<T1,T2>::initializer_node' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T1=boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::initializer_root,boost::mpl::int_<0>>
1>  ,            T2=boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list2<boost::shared_ptr<void>,boost::signals2::detail::foreign_void_shared_ptr>>
1>          ]
1>          D:\src\open-source\boost\boost/variant/variant.hpp(1339) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<T1,T2>::initializer_node' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T1=boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::initializer_root,boost::mpl::int_<0>>,boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list2<boost::shared_ptr<void>,boost::signals2::detail::foreign_void_shared_ptr>>>::initializer_node,boost::mpl::int_<1>>
1>  ,            T2=boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list1<boost::signals2::detail::foreign_void_shared_ptr>>
1>          ]
1>          D:\src\open-source\boost\boost/variant/variant.hpp(1555) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::variant<boost::shared_ptr<void>,boost::signals2::detail::foreign_void_shared_ptr,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::initializer' being compiled
1>          D:\src\open-source\boost\boost/variant/variant.hpp(1732) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::variant<boost::shared_ptr<void>,boost::signals2::detail::foreign_void_shared_ptr,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::convert_construct<boost::shared_ptr<void>>(T &&,int,boost::mpl::false_)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=boost::shared_ptr<void>
1>          ]
1>          D:\src\open-source\boost\boost/variant/variant.hpp(1732) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::variant<boost::shared_ptr<void>,boost::signals2::detail::foreign_void_shared_ptr,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::convert_construct<boost::shared_ptr<void>>(T &&,int,boost::mpl::false_)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=boost::shared_ptr<void>
1>          ]
1>          D:\src\open-source\boost\boost/signals2/slot_base.hpp(49) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::variant<boost::shared_ptr<void>,boost::signals2::detail::foreign_void_shared_ptr,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::variant<boost::shared_ptr<void>>(T &&,void *,void *)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=boost::shared_ptr<void>
1>          ]
1>          D:\src\open-source\boost\boost/signals2/slot_base.hpp(49) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::variant<boost::shared_ptr<void>,boost::signals2::detail::foreign_void_shared_ptr,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::variant<boost::shared_ptr<void>>(T &&,void *,void *)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=boost::shared_ptr<void>
1>          ]
```

Is there any workaround to use `boost` and still use memory leak detection on Windows?

Comment: The code you are inserting into your source adds a macro that redefines `new`.  That seems rather daring.  It is entirely capable of clashing with other, equally daring facilities.  Boost could very well be such a facility, but I cannot confirm it.

Comment: Well, it is normal to redefine `new` in Visual C++. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx It looks like `boost` simply ignores this compatibility issue.

Comment: If you ignore the unhelpful error messages and actually look at the boost code where the errors are occurring you can get an idea of what is going on even though it seems daunting.  Once you identify the problem though, I'm really not sure if you will be able to easily introduce a fix.

Comment: That Microsoft (of all people) suggests redefining `new` does not make it *normal* to do so, even in VC++.  Moreover, I note that the Microsoft document you referenced only says you must do so to see file and line-number information in the leak report.  Assuredly that is useful, but leak detection itself does not depend on it.  You might even find that Boost is already redefining `new` in the needed manner.  If the redefinition is the source of the problem, then removing it -- or deferring it past inclusion of the Boost headers -- might be a viable workaround.